# .net call php function

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

I am trying to call a php function from .net. I tried to a webrequest method but I am not sure how to specify the function to call in the url. A link below shows the method I am trying to call.

Thanks in advance for any help

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to create a webpage on the PHP server that calls the function you want, and returns the results (ideally in SOAP or XML format).  Then, you can GET that webpage through the .NET WebRequest mechanism as you pointed out.

Comment: I am not sure I fully follow what you mean. Why would I need to create a webpage just to call the other webpage. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I don't know - why would you need to do this?  Perhaps you can provide some more details on your situation and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jim - You cannot simply "call" a php method.  You have to use the method Mike suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To call the function from C# you have to create a PHP file that executes the function, for example

`http://www.somesite.com/ScriptWithTheFunction.php`

with the content:

```
<?php 

    //your includes here

    //You can set the value of $password from a $_GET parameter
    echo wp_hash_password( $password );
```

and with C# you use `WebRequest` to get the output of the function (The same response you get from visiting `http://www.somesite.com/ScriptWithTheFunction.php` with your web browser)